# Summary View TypeError: Groupfield is null

Tags: error

I'm setting up SharePoint 2013 and I inserted a News Announcement as a webpart on my homepage, but when I try to modify the webpart and change the view to "Summary View" I get this error message:

> TypeError: 'GroupField' is null or not an object

Has anyone seen this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got exactly the same problem in the same situation. But mine won't fix itself. Any guidance anyone can give to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind! An hour later it resolved itself. I don't know how, but it did.